# How to read data only for a specified period with netCDF4 module?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I'd like to read netCDF data for a specified period.
What I try to read ncfile is named `file.nc` and the part of information of `ncdump -c file.nc` is

```
dimensions:
lat = 1 ;
lon = 1 ;
time = UNLIMITED ; // (744 currently)
variables:
float lat(lat) ;
    lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
    lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
float lon(lon) ;
    lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
    lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
double time(time) ;
    time:units = "hours since 2015-07-01 01:00:00" ;
    time:long_name = "time" ;
double rain(time, lat, lon) ;
    rain:_FillValue = -999000000. ;
    rain:units = "K" ;
    rain:standard_name = "temperature" 
data:

lat = 1 ;
lon = 1 ;
time = -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... 
737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742 ;
```

And here is my script for reading this ncfile.

```
import netCDF4

nc = netCDF4.Dataset(file.nc, 'r')
data = nc.variables['temperature'][:] #I want to read between 2015-07-20 00:00 to 2015-07-24 23:00
```

I want to read between specific period with detecting the start date and end date. How to go abount it ?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use xarray for this; see e.g. this question/answer as a demonstration of how easy it is to select time periods with xarray: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323528/netcdf-time-series-slice-with-python-3/51336703#51336703

Comment: It would boil down to something as simple as `import xarray as xr; nc = xr.open_dataset(file.nc, 'r'); p = nc.sel(time=slice('2015-07-20 00:00', '2015-07-24 23:00'))`

Comment: @Bart Thank you for replying. By the way, `type(p)` is `<xarray.Dataset>`. Do you know how to extract data (temperature data) and convert to `numpy` ?

Comment: Something like `p['temperature'].values` should give you a normal Numpy array.

Comment: @Bart I got it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Bart suggested, xarray is the way to go.  Here's the answer w/o xarray. `NetCDF4.date2index()` is the answer.

```
import netCDF4
import dateutil.parser

nc = netCDF4.Dataset(file.nc, 'r')

# all_times variable includes the time:units attribute
all_times = nci.variables['time']

sdt = dateutil.parser.parse("2015-07-20T00:00:00")
edt = dateutil.parser.parse("2015-07-24T23:00:00")

st_idx = netCDF4.date2index(sdt, all_times)
et_idx = netCDF4.date2index(edt, all_times)

data = nc.variables['temperature'][st_idx:et_idx+1,:] #I want to read between 2015-07-20 00:00 to 2015-07-24 23:00
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `date2index`, nice option. My solution with NetCDF4 (which I didn't dare to post) was slightly less elegant ;-)

Comment: @Eric Bridger I also did it with your suggestion. Thank you for replying.